# Overloading Base Data Types

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is it possible to overload a base type like `char` or `int` with extra operators?

What I tried:

```
bool char::operator[](const int param) {
    if (param < 8) {
        return (*this) & std::pow(2, param);
    }
    else {
        exit(13);
    }
}
```

What I want to happen:
I want the function to return the value of the bit at position `param` of the character variable.

What Happens:
It does not compile. Error: `'bool' followed by 'char' is illegal.`

Comment: Question at the start of the post. Answer at the end. Does one need to elaborate.

Comment: `^` is the bitwise exclusive-or operator. I believe you are looking for bitwise disjunction ("and"), which is written `&`. And `pow` returns a floating-point value; if you want to compute 2 to the power of a small integer, use the left-shift operator: `1U<<param` (or `1UL<<param` if you expect `param` to be larger than the bitwidth of an `int`. Or even `1ULL<<param`...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  `char` is a fundamental type, and as such you cannot overload its member operator, as it has no members.

Furthermore, `operator[]` cannot be implemented as a non-member function.  So in this case, I am afraid you are out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can't overload char or use 'this' since it represents the instantiation of a class but what if you can create your own class Char or CHAR etc... similar to a String class or the way you can write Lists or Stacks using your own class using vectors.
[Here you go](http://ideone.com/K6MOb7)

So you can have something like

```
class Char{
    private:
        char cx;
    public:
        Char(){}
        Char(char ctmp):cx(ctmp){}
        Char(Char &tmp):cx(tmp.cx){ }
        ~Char(){ }

        char getChar(void){ return this->cx; }

         // operator implementations here
        Char& operator = (const Char &tmp)
        {
            cx = tmp.cx;
            return *this;
        }
        Char& operator = (char& ctmp){
            cx = ctmp;
            return *this;
        }
        bool operator[](const int param) {
            if (param < 8) { return (*this) & std::pow(2, param); }
            else { exit(13); }
        }
};
```